# no ConnectionString but my website can run

Tags: asp.net

I have website project and there is no connectionString in web.config, in other words I deleted its ConnectionString. now I expect the error but no error, Although I rebuilt website several times...
is here anyone what is my problem?

Comment: do you use a database?

Comment: Im implementing membership. so I have...

Comment: Why you see a problem when is running ? :) Please give us the web.config to give more help...

Comment: yes u right but I want to add this DB to my DB, now if I join both, I dont know where I must be set ConnectionString...ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have no connection string and the program can still connect to the DB its highly likely the web.config file has been cached and not reloaded yet.

Although IIS does monitor the web.config file there are certain circumstances where its not notified about file updates and you have to manually recycle the app pool (such as hosting a website off of a NFS share).

Comment: its say that is rebuild the site several times, do not see cache problem here.

Comment: even with a web rebuild (especially on NFS) the app pool may not be recycled and the web.config file can still be cached by IIS. Had it happen to many times to recall :( Really wish IIS would use better file detection techniques.

Comment: If you say so.. I do not have this experience, but I can not say that can not be happens from the moment you say so.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you website must not be using any Database actions or calls hence it works For e.g. I can go to google home page because it must be not using any DB stuff when I login to my google account thats the time it will make DB calls for my details etc...